# How can I make an actionPerformed within a switch statement?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I am trying to make a simple program with a GUI that is command-prompt based (i.e. type in a command and click an enter button). Whenever the user clicks on the enter button, all information they typed in a JTextArea is processed, and then an output is given based off of their input (such as typing /exit to close the program).

Whenever the user types in /exit, a prompt comes up asking the user if they are sure they want to exit. However, as soon as that pops up, it's replaced by the invalid input message I put in if the user put in something that wasn't recognized. My only reasoning on why this happens is that the ActionListener class still has /exit stored in the inputHolder string, which is the string I use to store the user's inputs and have them processed.

```
package msai;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JTextArea output;
    JButton inputButton;
    JTextArea commandLine;
    String inputHolder;
    String invalid = "Invalid input!";

    public MainFrame() {
        super("MSAI");
        setLookAndFeel();
        setSize(650, 350);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(flo);

        output = new JTextArea("Hi! I'm MSAI. Type any command to get started, or type /help for a list of commands and syntax!", 8, 40);
        inputButton = new JButton("ENTER");
        inputButton.addActionListener(this);
        commandLine = new JTextArea(8, 40);
        commandLine.setLineWrap(true);
        commandLine.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(commandLine, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        add(output);
        add(inputButton);
        add(scroll);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        inputHolder = commandLine.getText();
        switch(inputHolder) {
            "/exit":
                output.setText("Are you sure you want to terminate this session?");
                inputHolder = commandLine.getText();
                switch(inputHolder.toUpperCase()) {
                    case "YES":
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    case "NO":
                        output.setText("Your session has not been terminated.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        output.setText(invalid);
                        break;
            }
        } 
    }  
    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            "javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"
            );
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            //ignore error
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
    }
}
```

Currently my only thought process on how to solve this is to put another actionPerformed inside the /exit switch statement, but I am unsure on how to do that, or if that is even the best solution. I'll welcome any answers and feedback, just please don't be toxic!

Comment: `inputHolder` won't process the input again, until the user presses the `inputButton` again (confirming the request).  So, you will need to process the `/exit` request as one pass and what ever response the user types as a second pass, maybe using a state value to maintain context

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
output.setText("Are you sure you want to terminate this session?");
inputHolder = commandLine.getText();
```

The user hasn't updated the `commandLine` and pressed the button yet, so nothing has changed.  You need to "wait" till the user response a second time.

You will need to carry the "state" of the request over to next time `ActionPerformed` is called, for example...

```
private boolean wantsToExit = false
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    inputHolder = commandLine.getText();

    if (wantsToExit) {
        if (wantsToExit && inputHolder.equals("YES")) {
            // Better to close the frame and let the system deal with it
        } else if (wantsToExit && inputHolder.equals("NO")) {
            output.setText("Your session has not been terminated.");
        }
        wantsToExit = false;
    } else {
        switch(inputHolder) {
            "/exit":
                wantsToExit = true;
                output.setText("Are you sure you want to terminate this session?");
                break;
        } 
    }  
}
```

If you want to do it in a single flow, then you should consider using a `JOptionPane` to prompt the user instead

Comment: How would I do it with a JOptionPane? I'm so new to this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that code in your actionPeformed excutes entirely and the user has no way to entering YES or NO and clicking the "ENTER" button.  The inner switch executes whith inputHolder having the value "/exit" which leads to the default case.

You will need a way to distinguish the actions. You can use a flag to indicates if the user has issued an exit command.  If the flag is true, then execute the inner switch.  Otherwise, return from the method.

Here's the code that tries to be close to your original idea.

```
    boolean exitCommand = false;  //has the user issued exit command?


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        inputHolder = commandLine.getText();
        if (exitCommand){
            switch (inputHolder.toUpperCase()) {
                    case "YES":
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    case "NO":
                        exitCommand = false; //forget exit command.
                        output.setText("Your session has not been terminated.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        output.setText(invalid);
                        break;
                }
        }


        switch (inputHolder) {
            case "/exit": 
                exitCommand = true;
                commandLine.setText("");
                output.setText("Are you sure you want to terminate this session?");
                inputHolder = commandLine.getText();
                if (!exitCommand) {
                    exitCommand = true;
                    return;
                }  

        }
    }
```